# Whats the command to let rvm use default (like global) gemset for every new rails application I create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I have installed rvm after installing Mac OS Lion. The problem which I am facing is whenever I try to run a new Rails application, it gives me following error.

The problem gets resolved once choose a particular rvm. `$ rvm gemset use global`

I know about using .rvmrc file per project. But I don't want to keep on using this command every time I create a demo project. Why doesn't rvm uses the "global" gemset automatically every time I create new project?

I used [this documentation](http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/9/23/install-rails-ruby-mac) to install rvm.

```
JP:demo3 jayparteek$ rails s
/Users/jayparteek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:3:in `require': no such file to load -- action_dispatch (LoadError)
    from /Users/jayparteek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jayparteek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:48:in `require'
    from /Users/jayparteek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What do you mean "default gemset"? You shouldn't ever have to explicitly use the global gemset except when installing gems in it. By definition everything that's in the global gemset is in all gemsets for that ruby.

Comment: this could be like 'global'. Let me elaborate on my question. I open the terminal-> to go my 'sites' folder & fire up '$ rails new app'. When i follow these steps, i get the above error unless i tell rvm which gemset to use.

Comment: What gemset is it using to start with? Is the `action_dispatch` gem (and `rails`) installed in that gemset?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify a "default" gemset for a given ruby interpreter, by doing:

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p0@gemsetname --default
```

See: http://beginrescueend.com/gemsets/using/ and http://beginrescueend.com/gemsets/basics/

it's probably a better idea to use a specific gemset for each of your projects, together with it's specific Gemfile.  Problems could happen if you require '>= x.y.z' in your Gemfiles, and you do a `bundle update` in one project, but not in the other...

```
cd ProjectA
rvm gemset create projecta
rvm gemset use projecta

cd ProjectB
rvm gemset create projectb
rvm gemset use projectb
```

This way, although you update the gems in ProjectA via `bundle update` to the latest and greatest, they still don't get modified for ProjectB -- eliminating the possibility for interference between projects.

---

you can also add a .rvmrc file to a directory, e.g. your project directory.   RVM will then use the ruby-version and gem set listed in the .rvmrc file as the default for all sub-directories.

e.g. assuming that you have ruby 1.9.3 installed, and a gem set "rails_3.2" for that ruby version:

```
# cat .rvmrc
rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails_3.2
```

Comment: If you're using Bundler to manages projects you already have all the isolation you need. Separate gemsets or not the behavior of Bundler will still be the same.

Comment: if you use gemsets per project, a bundle update on one project and gemset can't modify the gem versions in the other projects / gemsets

Comment: And if you use Bundler it will never use the wrong version either. That is the whole point of Bundler. Gemsets are not needed to achieve that functionality.

Comment: bundler certainly keeps them separate, but if the user does a `gem list` s/he will see all installed gems, not just the one which are installed for that particular project.. if you use a gemset you see only the ones which are for this project.

Comment: Why are you using `gem list` in a project that uses Bundler? You should use `bundle list`. Just because a gem (or a particular version of a gem) is installed doesn't mean it gets used in your project. Regardless, what you say in your answer is not about `gem list`, it's about `bundle update` affecting a separate project that also uses Bundler, which is unequivocally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can make default gemset by using following command

```
rvm --default gemset use <gemsetname>
```

or

```
rvm gemset use <gemsetname> --default
```

For example, if you have rails4 gemset then you can make it default by

```
rvm --default gemset use rails4
```

or

```
rvm gemset use rails4 --default
```